# How to fetch the Hash Code of GitHub commit into databricks workspace?

Tags: python, github, databricks

How to fetch the Hash Code of GitHub commit into databricks workspace?

On Every commit in the github, we get a hash. I want to fetch that latest hash into databricks.

Answer (score 1):

If you [enabled Git integration](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/github-version-control.html) and the [synchronization of your work in Databricks with a remote Git repository](https://docs.databricks.com/repos.html), you can query that Git repository directly:

```
git ls-remote https://github.com/me/myRepo
```

That will give you the latest hash code (SHA1) of all the branches in that remote (synchronized) repository.

Comment: ohh....I will check that for sure. Just one query, I want to fetch the CSV files hash code which is not integrated via Databricks. I have manually commited it. If you can write actual code in one or two line, it would help me....

Comment: @HrishikeshThakurdesai Fetching a *file* is not the same as querying the SHA1. If you need files, you need to clone the synchonized repository, or to pull from it, in order to get the latest files.

Comment: Yes. I mean lets say that CSV file is getting modified on every commit. Then I would like to get the latest CSV file as well and its Hash. So that i can make sure that latest CSV is getting used for calculations further.

Comment: @HrishikeshThakurdesai If that file is modified with every commit, but is not committed itself, then it won't be synchronized with the GitHub repository. If it is itself committed, you will see it in the synchronized repository. Is it a databricks-specific file?

Comment: No, Its a separate CSV file which contains commands for calculations. These calculations are fetched and used in Databricks to apply on Spark Dataframe. I want to record that which CSV file is used and what was its Hash when I save the result.

Comment: Can u please send me some snapshot of code in Databricks workspace....it would be great help :)

Comment: @HrishikeshThakurdesai I don't know Databrick enough for that. I was simply answering your original question, which makes no mention of a CSV file. Only of hash codes.

Comment: Not an issues, you have atleast gave me some direction. I will certaily try and let you know. Thanks :)